# how to change default views filter url

Tags: 7, views

I have a views which filters films by genre and year, however the client would like urls in the following format:

```
/films/comedy/2009
```

however views is outputing the url like:

```
/films?genre=3&year=22
```

Any way to get round this?

Comment: same issue http://drupal.org/node/755060

Comment: Good to know other people facing same problem, be nice  to get a solution :)